# IllegalStateException occurring after single call to Java stream

Tags: java, junit, lambda, java-stream, jmockit

I have the code below using a Java 8 stream to add an ID to a list of objects. However, I keep getting the error 'stream has already been operated upon or closed'. However, I am only opening one stream, and the other code that is called does not use streams since I recently started pointing to JDK 1.8.

I will also note that I see the error using JUnit when testing, so not sure if that could be the problem.

Any ideas?

Edit: removed original code and added simplified example. It appears the issue is related to using @Mocked method parameters.

```
public class FooService {

public Collection<Course> getCourses() {
    List<Course> result = Arrays.asList(new Course(), new Course(), new Course());
    result.stream().forEach(c -> c.setUrl("foobar"));

    return result;
}

}
```

Course

```
public class Course {

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

private String url;

}
```

Test code

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class FooServiceTest {

@Tested
FooService foobarService;

@Test
public void testOne(@Mocked Collection<String> bar) {
    foobarService.getCourses();
}

@Test
public void testTwo(@Mocked Collection<String> bar) {
    foobarService.getCourses();
}

}
```

If I removed the @Mocked methods the test passes without the Stream error.

Comment: I don't see how it could happen in your code, are you sure about the posted code? Could you make it more minimal?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: updated with simplified example

Comment: Why are you using `Stream` at all? You can just use `forEach` on the list directly.

Comment: My guess is you are mocking `Collection` without specifying the mocked method invocations that will be called on the collection and what they should return.  The `Stream` will request a `Spliterator` which may be mocked as well.  Because you are not specifying method invocations on mocked objects, JMockit will return default values for those methods, which may not follow Spliterator semantics.  I'm not an expert, but I know that with Iterator, apis rely on the result of hasNext() to stop them from calling "next()" when the iterator is exhausted, which would cause an exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you want / need to mock Collections in your code? The @Mocked annotation means that all Collections of generic type String will be mocked in any code that you execute from that method. I'm not quite sure why you would want to do that, but if you do, you will probably need to specify behavior for Collections using an Expectations block.

Comment: This is correct. Normally (ie, pre-Java 8), a `@Mocked` interface would have no effect at all when the mocked instance doesn't get used. However, in Java 8 we have *default methods*, and the `Collection` interface did get a `spliterator()` method containing a default implementation in the interface itself; this method therefore gets mocked by JMockit for *all* collection instances. This said, JMockit should probably exclude these default methods from being mocked in the `Collection` interface (and other such interfaces).